# Cant add to root in seperate class?

Tags: java, javafx, root

Im working with javaFX and i would like to add a Rectangle object to the game root from a seperate player class. Therfor i created a getRoot function in my Game, and tried adding the rectangle from my player class. Although for some reason it just dosent work.

```
public class Test {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("loaded");
        GameScene gameScene = new GameScene();
        gameScene.getRoot().getChildren().add(new Sprite(50,50,50,50, Color.GREEN,"TEST", 1, 0));
    }
}

public class GameScene {

    private Group root = new Group();

    public Scene getScene(){

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.BLACK);
        Test test = new Test();
        test.run();

        return scene;
    }

    public Group getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

}
```

The gameScene is still just empty when i run it, although the "loaded" string is printed to the console.

Comment: The sprite class is perfectly fine btw, as the exact same code, put inside the GameScene renders the rectangle.

Comment: What "loaded" string? What `getRoot()` method. your example does not show them.

Comment: Thes system.out.println string at the top of the run() method. I forgot to add the getRoot function, its added now tho.

Comment: `GameScene gameScene = new GameScene();` creates a new `GameScene` instance that is different to the one calling `Test.run`, therefore the `root` field value that is modified is different from the one that is used as scene root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for modifying root by another class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GameScene extends Application {

    private Group root;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        root = new Group();
        stage.setScene(getScene());
        stage.show();
    }

    public Scene getScene(){

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Test test = new Test();
        test.run(root);
        return scene;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class Test {

    public void run(Group root) {
        root.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.BLACK));
    }
}
```